# Volume and mass of inertia of the body bounded $z=0$, $x=0$, $y^2=x^3$, $y+z=1$ and $z-y=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Given
$$z=0$$
$$x=0$$
$$y^2=x^3$$
$$y+z=1$$
$$z-y=1$$

I need to find the volume $V$ and mass of inertia $I_x$ but I have not really a clue of how to choose my bounds for my triple integrals

I was thinking

$$-1\le y\le 1$$
$$0\le z\le 1+y$$
$$0\le x\le y^{\frac{2}{3}}$$

Comment: I think you meant *moment* of inertia?

Comment: Yeah I think so, I'm not sure how it's called in english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameterization is slightly incorrect. The upper bound of $z$ should instead be the shortest vertical distance between the plane $z=0$ and either plane $z=1-y$ and $z=1+y$, which is captured by $z=\min\{1-y,1+y\}$. The subsequent volume integral (taking advantage of symmetry about $y=0$) would be

$$\begin{align*}V &= \int_{-1}^1 \int_0^{\min\{1-y,1+y\}} \int_0^{y^{2/3}} dx \, dz \, dy \\[1ex]
&= \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} \int_0^{y^{2/3}} dx \, dz \, dy + \int_{-1}^0 \int_0^{1+y} \int_0^{y^{2/3}} dx \, dz \, dy \\[1ex]
&= 2 \int_0^1 \int_0^{1-y} \int_0^{y^{2/3}} dx \, dz \, dy\end{align*}$$